# string variable showing assigned value from listobject.name as empty

Tags: excel, vba, string, listobject

I'm trying to assign the name of a ListObject (a table) to a string variable, however the variable is showing empty value eventhough the listobject name does exist and is correctly identified:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'0. Declaration and Initialization of Variables
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    
Dim dateMasterIP, dateCurrentIP As Date
    dateMasterIP = Range("rngMasterIPDate").Value
    
Dim wsName, strDataMasterIP, strDataCurrentIP, strNewSheetName As String
    strDataMasterIP = "tbIP" & Year(dateMasterIP)

Dim objTable As ListObject
Dim TestForTable As String
Dim rngTestCell As Range

Dim rngIPDates() As Variant
    rngIPDates = Range("rngIPDates").Value

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'2. Procedure Module
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
    wsName = wsSheet.Name
    
    If Left(wsName, 2) = "IP" Then
        Set wsSheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        Set objTable = wsSheet.ListObjects(1)
        
        Dim dateInspection As Variant
        For Each dateInspection In rngIPDates
            If Year(dateInspection) = Right(wsName, 4) Then
                strDataCurrentIP = objTable.Name
                dateCurrentIP = CDate(dateInspection)
            End If
            Call DataAlignment(wb, strDataMasterIP, strDataCurrentIP, dateMasterIP, dateInspection)
        Next dateInspection
    End If
Next wsSheet
```

[As can be seen in this screenshot, the objTable.name correctly throws the table name (i.e., "tbIP2018"):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEcRd.png)

[However the strDataCurrentIP evaluates to an empty value as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A0st.png)

I'm trying to get the table name stored into the strDataCurrentIP variable, however I'm getting an empty value

Answer (score 1):

from another site I got this answer and it worked:

change:

```
If Year(dateInspection) = Right(wsName, 4) Then
```

to:

```
If Year(dateInspection) = CLng(Right(wsName, 4)) Then
```

Comment: I believe this could work. but `Year` returns integer values so the correct function should be `CInt()` instead of `CLng()`. Since `Right()` and `Left()` and such are string functions they return strings then the values are not equal.

Comment: Oh.. realized now it's OPs own answer.